# Should I use npm install or npm update to keep my code up to date?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

So I'm working on some projects within my work space and I notice that a lot of my dependencies are roughly 3 years old, including React itself.  The thing I'm worried about is that if I run `npm install` or `npm update` that things might break and I could run into a plethora of issues.  In my scenario I would like to know if it is better for me to do an `npm install`, `npm update`, or just leave it the way it is? (which I'm sure no one would recommend).

Here is our package.json file

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/entry",
    "start-dev": "npm-run-all --parallel build babel-node",
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build-linux": "clear && webpack && clear && yarn build-server && clear && yarn start",
    "build-windows": "cls && webpack && cls && yarn build-server && cls && yarn start",
    "build-server": "babel src/server -d src",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "babel-node": "nodemon --exec babel-node src/server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.358.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "express": "latest",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "google-maps-react": "^1.1.4",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.6.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.0",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.14",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.7.0",
    "normalize.css": "7.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.10.1",
    "promise-mysql": "^3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.14",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "table2csv": "^1.1.1",
    "twilio": "^3.24.0",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.5.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

I already tried updating my react and react-dom versions to the latest, but I started getting warnings about componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps being outdated.  I tried updating react-router-dom to get rid of some of those warnings, considering they were pointing to things like `Link, Route, Switch`, but that did not suppress them.

If anyone knows what the best way for me to go about this would be, and what the effects of `npm install` vs `npm update` would do to my system that would be great.  I know what each of them is capable of doing, but I'm just trying to be cautious and want to know which one would be better in my scenario.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you not using package locks? How can you guarantee that someone else receiving your code and running `npm install` will get node_modules identical to, and tested by, you?

Comment: @jarmod honestly probably not.  Keep in mind I work at a company where this code was here before me, so I'm trying to fix the things they should've been doing all this time.

Comment: Never too late to start ;-) The challenge with versions such as `^1.1.4` is that there's almost zero chance that someone cloning your code in the future and running `npm install` is going to get the same versions of code that you used and you tested with. So, they may fall victim to minor releases that introduce problems. This should not happen, but it does. So their `npm install` is analogous to your `npm update` -- you are both in uncharted territory. If package vendors made zero mistakes, then you're OK. You might even have improved things by gaining bug fixes and security patches.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get node packages up-to-date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51846801/how-to-get-node-packages-up-to-date)

Answer (score 12):

When you run `npm install` on a project, npm installs latest versions satisfying the semantic versioning ranges defined in your package.json. After initial install, re-running npm install does not update existing packages since npm already finds satisfying versions installed on the file system.

When you run `npm update` it freshen already installed packages. When you run npm update, npm checks if there exist newer versions in the repository that satisfy specified semantic versioning ranges and installs them.

I would say "bite the bullet" and update them to latest. It will be a tedious task but if you are looking to maintain this for longer run, it is your best bet.

Comment: So you're saying I should run npm update then?  In the case that it does break a bunch of things is there a way to revert the update?

Comment: nom update wouldn't get the latest version of the package. it respects semantic versioning. you need to use someting like this to bring every thing up to date https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates

Comment: `npm update` can get the latest version and can break a bunch of things, depending on what version semantics are used for your dependencies. The default behavior (versions like `^1.4.0`) will update the minor as high as it can go without updating the major. Since minor versions can include breaking changes in semver, it is possible to break your code. `npm install` will not touch already installed packages, but installs new ones at the highest compatible version like `npm update`.

Answer (score 2):

Updating stuff can break things or some dependencies will be deprecated after an update. I would not update anything unless it is necessary.

Comment: Honestly don't think Material UI supports anything lower than React v16.3, and I don't see support for React Bootstrap.